# How do you access the top tab/toolbar for iOS on Shell pages?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

I have been trying to set the gravity / positioning options for the top tab/toolbar (the layout that appears when you set two ShellContents to a Tab). This has worked on Android, as the Android Shell renderer exposes both `CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker` and `CreateTabLayoutAppearanceTracker`.

However, the iOS Shell renderer only exposes `CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker` in regards to tabs which only deals with (at least from what I understand) the bottom tab (higher hierarchically than ShellContent tabs).

I have tried to subclass `ShellItemRenderer`, but I couldn't find any properties related to what I wanted.

**How it appears on Android:**

[image: Appearance of top tab bar on Android]

Comment: can you put in some codes?

Comment: @VisualSharp What exactly do you want to see? I'm simply asking what renderer, appearance tracker or property / methods I need to use to access customisation for the top tabs.

Comment: @DaddyProphet Hi , it seems can not get the top toolbar from `CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker` easily, I will check that in iOS how to achieve that . If good news will update here later. :-)

Comment: @DaddyProphet Hi , I have found the solution and updated in answer, you can have a look at that when you have time. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to access the the top tab/toolbar for iOS on Shell pages. You need a subclass of `ShellSectionRootHeader`, which is itself a subclass of `UICollectionViewController` which is the native type that renders the top tab bar on iOS. Once you have that subclass, you can then override the `GetCell` method to get each individual item in the top tab bar and modify them. But in order to get to that point, you need to subclass and instantiate 2 more renderers beyond the `ShellRenderer`.

Here is the sample Renderer code in iOS :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Shell), typeof(CustomShellRenderer))]
namespace Xaminals.iOS
{
    public class CustomShellRenderer: ShellRenderer
    {
        protected override IShellSectionRenderer CreateShellSectionRenderer(ShellSection shellSection)
        {
            var shellSectionRenderer = new CustomShellSectionRenderer(this);
            return shellSectionRenderer;
        }
    }
    public class CustomShellSectionRenderer : ShellSectionRenderer
    {

        public CustomShellSectionRenderer(IShellContext context) : base(context)
        { }

        protected override IShellSectionRootRenderer CreateShellSectionRootRenderer(ShellSection shellSection, IShellContext shellContext)
        {
            var renderer = new CustomShellSectionRootRenderer(shellSection, shellContext);

            return renderer;
        }
    }

    public class CustomShellSectionRootRenderer : ShellSectionRootRenderer
    {
        public CustomShellSectionRootRenderer(ShellSection section, IShellContext context) : base(section, context)
        { }

        protected override IShellSectionRootHeader CreateShellSectionRootHeader(IShellContext shellContext)
        {
            var renderer = new CustomShellSectionRootHeader(shellContext);
            return renderer;
        }
    }

    public class CustomShellSectionRootHeader : ShellSectionRootHeader
    {
        public CustomShellSectionRootHeader(IShellContext context) : base(context)
        {
            
        }

        public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell(collectionView, indexPath) as ShellSectionHeaderCell;

            // Set desired font here 
            //cell.Label.Font = UIFont.ItalicSystemFontOfSize(11);

            var layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
            layout.MinimumInteritemSpacing = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width / 8;
            layout.SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width/4, bottom: 0, right: 0);

            collectionView.CollectionViewLayout = layout;

            return cell;
        }
    }

    public class CustomUICollectionViewFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    {
        public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[] LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(CGRect rect)
        {
            return base.LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect);

        }

    }
}
```

The effect:

[image]

Comment: I am wondering if this answer could possibly help to resolve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397674/append-a-control-above-upper-to-the-shell-app-bar-without-altering-it

Comment: @Cfun Hi, I think you could have a try with custom ShellRenderer to modify the Toolbar. Not sure whether it works, but this should be the correct direction to do. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers#android-example

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Already tried several things with custom renderer in the past without sucess, lately came to know that the ToolBar stack elements horizontal (so whatever I add will be beside other elemnts not above) while the appbar (parent of toolbar) stacks them vertically, I have no idea how to customize the appbar even searched here and there.

Comment: @Cfun I think it's not easy to achieve that in Shell. If you are not using Shell, you could custom a `NavigationRenderer` to moidfy the `Toolbar.xml` in native android. Now I have no idea about Shell Renderer.

Comment: Seems to be some working solution here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1180648/xamarin-and-maui-shell-tabs-not-rendering-correctl