# Append a control above/upper to the Shell App bar without altering it

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-appbarlayout, custom-renderer, xamarin.forms.shell

I am trying to add a layer that can be any control (for example let's take a `Label`) above the `Shell` App bar (Navigation bar), so that it will be available on all pages. For this I tried to use `TitleView`, which obviously won't fulfills my requirement (see **screenshots** below).

**ATTEMPT**

**Page1.xaml:**

```
<ContentPage...>
...
  <Shell.TitleView>
     <StackLayout Spacing="0">
       <Label Text="Hello world" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
       <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference page1}, Path=Title}"/>
     </StackLayout>
  </Shell.TitleView>
</ContentPage>
```

**AppShell.xaml:**

```
<Shell...>
...
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <Tab Title="Tab1">
            <ShellContent Title="Page1"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"/>

            <ShellContent Title="Page2"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}"/>
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Tab2">
            <ShellContent Title="Page1"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"/>

            <ShellContent Title="Page2"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}"/>
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
</Shell>
```

So what I am trying to achieve is resumed in 2 points:

1. The `Label` should be on top of the whole App bar (`FlyoutIcon` + `TitleView`), not on top of `TitleView` only, as clarified in the screenshots.
2. At the same time the original style of the `ContentPage.Title` already in place should not be altered.

**Original Page Title**

[image: Original Title]

**Attempt**

[image: Attempt]

**Desired Result**

[image: Desired]

Bonus question:

It seems the `Shell` App bar is built from two parts `FlyoutIcon` and `TitleView`. How/where Xamarin.Forms is building the `Shell` layout? a brief explanation or pointing to the relevant Class in the [XF Github repo](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/) will be very appreciated.

Tried using some Shell custom renderers without success.

**EDIT**

- The appended control should be part of the `Shell` so that I can customize it content depending on the current page. That means also to be covered when `Flyout` is opened.

**EDIT 2**

The solution may come from the coming feature [Shell.AppBar](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/545). Meanwhile open for a solution at Android project level.

Comment: According to your description, you want modify Shell layout. I search some info, but don't find any solution, you can try to use custom render to do this.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT i already searched about custom renderer but i cannot find how to achieve that. Which method to override. There is little official info/documentation about that, only a list of virtual methods name that can be override. Also a good understanding of the Shell layout structure is required in order to achieve that (adding whole layer above).

Comment: Yes, there is little info about Shell, I still search some way to do this, if I find a way to do it, I will share it here. If you have a way to do it, please also share your solution.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I am now trying to understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64505934/5228202) because I believe hamburger button is part of Toolbar.

Comment: @Anything update?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT unfortunately no answer to my other question yet about `Shellcontent_Toolbar`. Also I am waiting for a reply from xf dev team regagding the implementation of `Shell.AppBar` like mentioned in my post edit link.

Comment: You can also create new thread at github, and if you have any update, please share here, thanks.