# How to add Banner In between Status bar and Navigation bar (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Currently i am trying to add offline banner in between Status bar and Navigation bar.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="OfflineBannerDemo.BasePage"
             x:Name="basePageCodeBehind">
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <!-- MainContent -->
            <ContentView x:Name="MainContentView"
                             BackgroundColor="Blue"
                             Content="{Binding Source={x:Reference basePageCodeBehind}, Path=MainContent}" />
            <!-- ConnectivityView -->
            <Grid x:Name="connectivityGrid"
                      VerticalOptions="Start"
                      Opacity="0"
                      InputTransparent="True"
                      BackgroundColor="Red"
                      HeightRequest="25">
                <Label Text="Offline"
                           VerticalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="Small"
                           TextColor="White"
                            />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

using about code i manage to display it below the Navigation Bar as below

[image]

If there is anyway to add this in between status bar and Navigation bar
please let me know.

Thank You.

Comment: Close question under shell https://stackoverflow.com/q/64397674/5228202

Comment: this is not work with me.

Comment: @ChanduRanwala Seems that you want to change page UI layout, I search some info, you can modify page's content UI, but seems that can not modify UI that displaying in Device.